# rsync backup messes up permissions on files

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, android, rsync

I use rsync backup on my Android device to backup some files from my device to my *nix server.
It sort of works, except the target directory and all files under it have their file mode flags set to 075, making them unaccessible to the owner (me).
I guess the flaw is with rsync backup, but I haven't found a way to remedy that.
Is there a way to have a job triggered, when files are transferred via ssh?

My current workaround is to have a cron job setting the file flags to 755 at a regular interval.

I'm using the following rsync command:

```
rsync -rptgo --progress --delete-after -e "ssh -y -p 22  -i '/sdcard/dss_key'" /sdcard/myfolder user@server:~/
```

Comment: Please provide the rsync command you used.

Comment: @mpy Please see the edit, as I provided the flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the permissions on your mobile device (source) are set to `075`. If invoked with the `-p` parameter `rsync` preserves the permissions.

> When this option is off, permissions are set as follows:
>
> o      Existing  files  (including  updated  files)  retain their existing permissions, though the --executability option
>                        might change just the execute permission for the file.
>
> o      New files get their "normal" permission bits set to the source file’s permissions masked with the receiving direc‐
>                        tory’s default permissions (either the receiving process’s umask, or the permissions specified via the destination
>                        directory’s default ACL), and their special permission bits disabled except in the  case  where  a  new  directory
>                        inherits a setgid bit from its parent directory.
>
> *from rsync's manpage*

So, you probably have to use

```
rsync -rtg --progress --delete-after -e "ssh -y -p 22 -i '/sdcard/dss_key'" /sdcard/myfolder user@server:~/
```

I also omitted the `-o` (preserve owner) flag, which is only effective, if you log into the destination as `root`, which you don't do, according to the given command.

Comment: thanks a lot. Now it works great. I did read the rsync man page, but probably wasn't smart enough to conclude what you pointed out to me here. ;-)

Comment: @TheRoadrunner: Sometimes the problem with man pages is, that they are _too long_ -- and if you don't know the keyword to search for you are lost `;)`